# How to Show $g(x)=\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^k}\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ for $k>\frac{n}{2p}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> How to Show $g(x)=\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^k}\in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ for $k>\frac{n}{2p}$

As $k>\frac{n}{2p}\implies 2kp>n$

Claim: $\int_{\mathbb R^n}|g|^p<\infty$

$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{kp}}dx\leq \int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{1}{(|x|^n)}dx$

I do not know how to concluded integrability of function .
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Go to the generalized spherical coordinates (aka hyperspherical coordinates).

Comment: @thing Dear Sir Please can you explain some more as i do not know about generalised spherical coordinates

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: In order not to make a problem appear in 0, you have to separate the integral in two: one integral on the ball $B$ of center 0 and radius 1 and the other on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B$